# java.util.Calendar.get* and java.util.Calendar.set* are blocking

Tags: java, multithreading, blocking, java-6, java.util.calendar

on a multi thread application, there are locked threads, as i get the threaddump, it seems to be about the java.util.Calendar class, the object is created using `Calendar.getInstance()` which returns `new` Instance. Do you have any comment.
here is a sample of the thread dump;

```
"QuartzScheduler_Worker-128" prio=10 tid=0x00007f48844fe800 nid=0xb75f runnable [0x00007f43f01bd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
       at java.util.SimpleTimeZone.getOffset(SimpleTimeZone.java:656)
       - locked <0x00007f4950c99780> (a java.util.SimpleTimeZone)
       at java.util.SimpleTimeZone.getOffsets(SimpleTimeZone.java:550)
       at java.util.SimpleTimeZone.getOffset(SimpleTimeZone.java:522)
       ...


"QuartzScheduler_Worker-124" prio=10 tid=0x00007f48844f6800 nid=0xb75a waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f43f05c3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
       at java.util.SimpleTimeZone.getOffsets(SimpleTimeZone.java:533)
       - waiting to lock <0x00007f4950c99780> (a java.util.SimpleTimeZone)
       at java.util.SimpleTimeZone.getOffset(SimpleTimeZone.java:522)
       at java.util.SimpleTimeZone.inDaylightTime(SimpleTimeZone.java:834)
       at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo.getOffsets(ZoneInfo.java:282)
       ...
```

EDIT: jdk version is 1.6._021

Comment: Are you creating one object of Calendar and sharing amongst threads or do you have a single object per thread? Calendar is not thread safe so you must do the latter.

Comment: Calendar is created for every thread using the Calendar.getInstance method which returns new Calendar object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just managed to take a thread dump at the instant that two threads were contending over the lock on a shared `SimpleTimeZone` object.  One thread holds the lock and is runnable.  The other thread is waiting for the lock.

There is nothing particularly note-worthy about this ... to my mind.

(I can't find the source-code online that gives a precise match to those line-numbers.  But the versions of `java.util.SimpleTimeZone` that I can find don't reveal anything interesting.  Hint: in the JDK for the precise version of Java that you are using, you should find a ZIP file of source code for the libraries.  Look at the sourcecode for this class ....)

Comment: I have added the jdk version which is 1.6.0_21

Comment: I don't have easy access to the sourcecode for 1.6.0_21.  You do.